# STM32cubeIDE ignore my code and using MX config

Tags: c, stm32f0, stm32cubemx

I have a question. Is there any option to disable CubeMx in STM32cubeIDE?

I just want use UART. So I write PINs and UART configuration in my main.c file. However CubeMX already had UART's pins configured and completely ignored my pins configuration.

It is very annoying when I dont know if i have to configure something in code or CubeMx.

Thank in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just create new project, wrote UART configuration and it didn't work. So then I check cube and saw pins with description UART pin TX and RX.

Now i comment my pin config code and it still work. UART send and receive data. For me its strange.